# Does Surge Spike Protector box can protect my PC even from Thunderbolts?

Tags: surge-protection, earth

My house isn't wired for an Earth ground. I am using a Surge/Spike Suppressor box to protect my computer.

Will this box protect the computer during lightning strikes? Is the design of the suppressor such that it requires the presence an Earth ground?

Comment: Go pikachu, thunderbolt!

Comment: Direct or indirect

Comment: Why are senior users so frickin' hostile to legitimate questions? 4 close votes?! Really?! It's an implicit question about the design of surge suppressors. Why isn't that appropriate?!

Comment: @DrFriedParts: It isn't about the design of surge suppressors in general; it's about the design of a particular (unnamed) commercial surge suppressor. We can't answer such a question here.

Comment: @Dave ...and why isn't it about the design of surge suppressors in general? Seems rather pejorative to dismiss it for that reason. You could answer this question with a survey of suppressor technologies, focus on the most common consumer architecture, or cover earth grounding (as the 2 answers have done). Instead we've just kicked, yet another, new user in the teeth and adding nothing of value in the process.

Comment: @DrFriedParts: That isn't how this site works. And now you've hijacked the question, putting your own words into the OP's mouth, which is completely inappropriate, and I'm going to roll it back. If you want to ask that broader question, make it a separate one, linking to this one if you want the context. But I bet that question would be closed as being "too broad" anyway.

Comment: @dave -- You didn't roll back far enough. Those are still my edits.

Comment: @DrFriedParts: Yes, your first edit was fine. Your second edit crossed the line.

Answer (score 2):

Without an earth wire or a lightning rod, a lightning bolt will fry everything in your house.
A surge protector is unlikely to help you in this case.

Comment: A surge protector with Line to Neutral protection will help in the case where the strike is some distance away from the PC/house (like more than 1.6 km / 1 mile). Only industrial sized protectors have a chance if it's a "little" strike near by. No earth means there is a much greater chance of people and equipment getting damaged in all cases and at greater distances from the strike..

Comment: **Short version:** _No_ surge protector can save anything from a direct lightning strike. The only difference for any device/scheme is how close the strike can be before everything explodes. Most of the time you may as well not bother, unless the strike happens in the relatively narrow window where the protection can make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet in this case is to hire a qualified electrician to install a suitable surge protector at your power Service Entrance.  The electrical code requires that you have a suitable ground connection at that point anyway.

The professional that you hire may suggest that you install extra ground rods when the surge protector is installed.